# Why isn't it an error?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

The following program is a recursive program to find the maximum and minimum of an array.(I think! Please tell me if it is not a valid recursive program. Though there are easier ways to find the maximum and minimum in the array, I'm doing in the recursive manner only as a part of a exercise!)

This program works correctly and produces the outputs as expected.

In the comment line where I have marked "Doubt here!", I am unable to understand why an error is not given during compilation. The return type is clearly an integer array (as specified in the method definition), but I have not assigned the returned data to any integer array, but the program still works. I was expecting an error during compilation if I did it this way, but it worked. If someone would help me figure this out, it'd be helpful! :)

```
import java.io.*;
class MaxMin_Recursive
{
    static int i=0,max=-999,min=999;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader B = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int[] inp = new int[6];
        System.out.println("Enter a maximum of 6 numbers..");
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
            inp[i] = Integer.parseInt(B.readLine());
        int[] numbers_displayed = new int[2];
        numbers_displayed = RecursiveMinMax(inp);
        System.out.println("The maximum of all numbers is "+numbers_displayed[0]);
        System.out.println("The minimum of all numbers is "+numbers_displayed[1]);
    }
    static int[] RecursiveMinMax(int[] inp_arr)     //remember to specify that the return type is an integer array 
    {   
        int[] retArray = new int[2];
        if(i<inp_arr.length)
            {
                if(max<inp_arr[i])
                    max = inp_arr[i];
                if(min>inp_arr[i])
                    min = inp_arr[i];
                i++;
                RecursiveMinMax(inp_arr);       //Doubt here!
            }
        retArray[0] = max;
        retArray[1] = min;
        return retArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, but I would be trying some other way to get the program to work! I just tried this. Was worth a shot! :D :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The return type is clearly an integer array (as specified in the method definition), but I have not assigned the returned data to any integer array, but the program still works.

Yes, because it's simply not an error to ignore the return value of a method. Not as far as the compiler is concerned. It may well represent a bug, but it's a perfectly *valid* use of the language.

For example:

```
Console.ReadLine(); // User input ignored!
"text".Substring(10); // Result ignored!
```

Sometimes I wish it *could* be used as warning - and indeed Resharper will give warnings when it can detect that "pure" methods (those without any side-effects) are called without using the return value. In particular, call which cause problems in real life:

- Methods on `string` such as `Replace` and `Substring`, where users assume that calling the method alters the existing string
- `Stream.Read`, where users assume that *all* the data they've requested has been read, when actually they should use the return value to see how many bytes have *actually* been read

There *are* times where it's entirely appropriate to ignore the return value for a method, even when it normally isn't for that method. For example:

```
TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value;
}
```

*Normally* when you call `TryGetValue` you want to know whether the key was found or not - but in this case `value` will be set to `default(TValue)` even if the key wasn't found, so we're going to return the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (as in C and C++) it is perfectly legal to discard the return value of a function. The compiler is not obliged to give any diagnostic.